# Trying to understand this schematic

Tags: schematics

https://github.com/hzeller/rpi-rgb-led-matrix/tree/master/adapter/active-3

This board is for level shifting 3.3v RPi GPIO output to 5v. There are 3 outputs; half of the pins of each output are unique to that output and the other half are common outputs.

Of course, the unique outputs are separately buffered; however, some of the common output pins share one buffer vs. other common output pins being separately buffered - particularly:

> The strobe, OE and clock signals are separately buffered for each connector.

Is there any benefit to separately buffering a common pin for each output?

Comment: Please include the schematic in the post so your readers don't have to follow links to understand the question. Use the image upload button. Your question title should give a clue as to what in the schematic you are trying to understand so that folks who know about that topic will be inclined to read it. You're not having trouble with the schematic - you're having trouble with the circuit design. Something like "Level shifter buffer fan-out" might be appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The board is designed to drive various LED matrix panels, many of which do not have datasheets or interface specs. Therefore it needs to have strong enough outputs to handle unknown loading and timing requirements.

Since the panels may be connected through long cables the capacitive loading could be quite high, causing slow transition times. The strobe, OE and clock signals are probably more critical than the address lines, so they are separately buffered for each output.

The github readme says:-

> RPi output drivers **have trouble driving longer cables**, in particular
>   with faster Raspberry Pis Version 2. This results in artifacts like
>   randomly showing up pixels, color fringes, or parts of the panel
>   showing 'static'.

This suggests that capacitive loading can be a problem if the drivers are not strong enough.

Comment: Alright, so then, instead of having all the level shifters for all of the panel inputs on that one board, would I get better performance by having separate level shifting boards placed right next to each panel input (and running a cable from each level shifting board to the RPi GPIO pins)?

Comment: HCT245 is rated for 35mA per pin. Pi is good for 16mA per pin at maximum strength. Best configuration for longest cable length would be to split it between the PI and buffer board - perhaps 1/3 Pi to buffer board and 2/3 buffer board to displays. If total length is shorter then you can decide which end you want the driver board closer to. If you use separate buffer boards then the PI has to drive 3 cables, so the capacitance will be up to 3 times higher and maximum cable length 3 times shorter.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any benefit to separately buffering a common pin for each output?

It's a best practice for daughter cards to buffer all input signals, and thereby isolate the "original" input signal from the "working" signal that's used by the components on the daughter card.

Imagine having multiple daughter cards stacked onto each other, and each card tries to use the original signal. Connecting more and more digital loads to the same signal path can easily overwhelm [the signal source's maximum fan-out specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fan-out).